# Return multiple rows when using AVG

Tags: mysql, sql, select, aggregate-functions

Why does this SQL query return only one result?

```
select data_value-AVG(data_value) from data
```

While the expected result is multiple rows with the difference to the average for each `data_value`.

Comment: `group by data_value`

Comment: Just so I'm clear on the requirements - are you trying to get the difference between each `data_value` to the average of **all** the data values?

Comment: @Mureinik yes that's it

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty grouping by data_value returns me 0 in each row

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ thought so, thanks - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't treat a single column (`data_value`, in this case) as both a grouping column and a non grouping column. You'd have to get them from different queries and join them:

```
SELECT     data_value - avg_data_value
FROM       data
CROSS JOIN (SELECT AVG(data_value) AS avg_data_value
            FROM   data) agg
```

If you don't want to get the same `data_value`s twice you could add a `distinct` modifier to the query:

```
SELECT     DISTINCT data_value - avg_data_value
FROM       data
CROSS JOIN (SELECT AVG(data_value) AS avg_data_value
            FROM   data) agg
```